# Standard error computation with interaction term

Tags: stata, interaction, standard-error, panel-data

I aimed at studying the effects of an exposure (E) on fetal growth estimated by repeated ultrasound measurements (n = 2 measures per participant in the following example). 
I used interaction terms of gestational age with exposure, in order to compute the effect of exposure at different age (using `lincom` in Stata).
I am surprised because the standard error of the effect estimates computed with lincomest (performed after xtmixed) are similar at 22.5 and 32.6 gestational weeks (both SEs = 8, while Beta = - 1  and - 19 g at 22.5 and 32.6 gestational weeks, respectively). I am wondering if I correctly used lincomest.

```
    gen expoAG =  expo*AG       /* Gestational Age */
gen expoAGsq =  expo*AGsq  /* squared of Gestational Age */

 xi : xtmixed EFW expo AG AGsq expoAG expoAGsq  if go_pen==1 ||n_ident:,  mle
lincomest _b[expo] +  _b[expoAG]*(22.5) + _b[expoAGsq]*(22.5*22.5)  /* Prediction at 22.5 GW */

 xi : xtmixed EFW expo AG AGsq expoAG expoAGsq  if go_pen==1 ||n_ident:,  mle
lincomest _b[expo] +  _b[expoAG]*(32.6) + _b[expoAGsq]*(32.6*32.6)  /* Prediction at 32.6 GW */
```

Comment: In the text editor there is a button with 2 brackets {}. Use that to post your code as code.

Comment: I've edited your post using our [editing tools](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Rather than Stata output, a small reproducible example would be helpful.